# android sqlite can't find table "No Such Table"

Tags: android, sqlite

It's really headache coz just some people having this trouble.. I tried many thing and really tired. I will give the code and pray :(

If anyone can solve really really thanks!!

StartActivity :

```
this.dhn = DataHelper.getDataHelper(this);

    File directory = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory() + File.separator + "data" + File.separator + "ko.tb" + File.separator + "databases");
    if(directory.exists())
    {
    }
    else
    {
        directory.mkdirs();
        updateDB();
    }
    directory = null;

    try {
        guid = this.dhn.Guid();

        if(this.dhn.getSettings("dbVersion") == null || Integer.parseInt(this.dhn.getSettings("dbVersion")) != Version || !this.dhn.isTableExists("UserInfo"))
        {
            updateDB(); 
        }
    }
    catch (SQLiteException e)
    {   
        updateDB();     
        guid = this.dhn.Guid();
    }


  public void updateDB()
    {
      this.dhn.close();

        try {
            InputStream myInput;

                myInput = getAssets().open("KelimeDB1.db");

            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = "/data/data/ko.tb/databases/"
                    + "KelimeDB1.db";

            // Open the empty db as the output stream
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            // Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
            buffer = null;
            outFileName = null;
            this.dhn.close();
            this.dhn = null;
            this.dhn = DataHelper.getDataHelper(this);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

DataHelper :

```
   private static DataHelper singleton;

public static DataHelper getDataHelper(Context context) {
        if (singleton == null) {
                singleton = new DataHelper(context);
                OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(singleton.context);
                singleton.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        if(!singleton.db.isOpen()){
                OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(singleton.context);
                singleton.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        singleton.context = context;
        return singleton;
}

private DataHelper(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
}

public void close() {
    if (singleton != null) 
    { 
        singleton.db.close();
        singleton.db = null;
        singleton = null;
        //this.db.close();
        this.db = null;
    }
}


public String Guid() {

    String SqlQuery = "SELECT Value FROM UserInfo WHERE key = 'guid'";
    String guid = null;
    Cursor cursor = this.db.rawQuery(SqlQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        guid = cursor.getString(0);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return guid;
}
```

Error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ko.tb/ko.tb.StartScreen}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: UserInfo: , while compiling: SELECT Value FROM UserInfo WHERE key = 'guid'
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: UserInfo: , while compiling: SELECT Value FROM UserInfo WHERE key = 'guid'
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1364)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1332)
at ko.tb.DataHelper.Guid(DataHelper.java:171)
at ko.tb.StartScreen.onCreate(StartScreen.java:76)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
... 11 more
```

Comment: I remember quite few people had this issue and it seems there is no definite answer for this except , do complete uninstall and change table name to something else. Still not guaranteed, but worked for few.

Comment: @Mert: `String outFileName = "/data/data/ko.tb/databases/"` - Seriously...don't do that. It may not be the cause of your problems but using a hard-coded path is only likely to cause new problems at some point anyway.

Comment: are you sure KelimeDB1.db contains that table? also since you're injecting a db from outside have you made sure all tables begin with a _id column? also your update procedure looks strange. why aren't you using the default SQLITEHELPER update / create process?

Comment: @MisterSquonk It should be ok. coz someone installed game works fine. but next update db installs again fail this time. If path has problem should have proglem at first time too, right? also what is your suggest I ll be glad to hear

Comment: @masi just %1-5 have this problem, so db or other stuff must be ok. I have more than 1000 rows information. how you suggest to update them rather than hard copy db file?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [this library out for managing your database](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) .  Its designed to assist developers that ship an app with a pre-created DB.

Comment: I just checked, but his writeExtractedFileToDisk and my updateDB do exactly same thing. I couldn't see any difference..